# CountIf of HTML tags in Excel

Tags: html, excel, excel-formula

How should i format COUNTIF to find HTML tags?

I tried `=countif(a2;"<b>")` - fail. Tried to decode HTML entities and then `=countif(a2;"&lt;b&gt;")` - same fail.

Comment: Can you share a picture of your document? It would be much easier to help with a more concrete example of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is some text arround `<b>` in `A2` cell contents, please try :

`=countif(a2;"*<b>*")`

`"<b>"` means exact search

`"*<b>*"` means contains